# NullPointerException when parsing file to make game map

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary, game-engine

I'm making a small game in 2D with view from above. I'm trying to do this:

1) I have a local file with map layout in .txt

2) Parse this file and make a map layout in game

3) Paint everything on screen

I (think so) successfully parsed file and put it into app, but it fails to draw, throwing NullPointerException. I understand that something here is null, but I fail to see what and where - from my point of view everything is where it should be.

Some code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s) );

        mapwidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        mapheight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


        String delimiters = " ";
        for (row = 0; row < mapheight; row++){
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delimiters);
            for (col = 0; col < mapwidth ; col++){
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);

            }
        }
```

This is function to parse file into program. First two lines read map width and height (from said file), then for every value in file I create a point in map[row][col]

This is another function responsible for making objects for every point of map

```
String wall ="Images/wall.jpg";
BufferedImage WALL = ImageIO.read(new File(wall));
if (map[row][col] == 0) { tile[row][col] = new Tile(WALL, false, true, false);  }
```

Last line is throwing an NullPointerException.
Tile is a single field in my game. It has four values - BufferedImage, blocked, walkable and destructable (last three are booleans). 
Also, it doesn't matter if I put code for making objects together with parsing code. Still I got exception.
I understand there is something missing here, but I can't figure out what.

Later I want to paint all tiles:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){               
    for (row=0; row < mapheight; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < mapwidth; col++){
            g.drawImage(
                    tile[row][col].getImage(),
                            row*tileSize,
                            col*tileSize,
                            null
                        );
```

I think it may have some errors, but I'm not sure. What I want to do, is to take every tile's image and paint it in appropriate row and column. Every field is a square (length = tileSize).

EDIT

Thank you all guys!

@Thierry - after debugging I found out that tile was still null and was not filling up. So, I made an empty instance of tile and put those two functions together. Right now it looks like this and works properly:

```
public GameTileMap(String s, int tileSize){
    this.tileSize = tileSize;

    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s) );

        mapwidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        mapheight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        map = new int[mapheight][mapwidth];
        tile = new Tile[mapheight][mapwidth];

        int mh = mapheight;
        int mw = mapwidth ;

        String delimiters = " ";
        for (row = 0; row < mh; row++){
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delimiters);
            for (col = 0; col < mw ; col++){
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);

            }
        }
        String wall ="Images/wall.jpg";
        String brick = "Images/brick.jpg";
        String grass ="Images/grass.jpg";
        String water = "Images/water.jpg";
        BufferedImage WALL = ImageIO.read(new File(wall));
        BufferedImage BRICK = ImageIO.read(new File(brick));
        BufferedImage GRASS = ImageIO.read(new File(grass));
        BufferedImage WATER = ImageIO.read(new File(water));
        for (row = 0; row < mh; row++){
            for (col = 0; col < mw ; col++){

        if (map[row][col] == 0) { tile[row][col] = new Tile(GRASS, false, true, false);  }
        else if (map[row][col] == 1) {tile[row][col] = new Tile(BRICK, true, false, true);}
        else if (map[row][col] == 2) {tile[row][col] = new Tile(WALL, true, false, false);}
        else if (map[row][col] == 3) {tile[row][col] = new Tile(WATER, false, false, false);}
        else {tile[row][col] = new Tile(GRASS, false, true, false);};
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Comment: Is this the code causing your exception: `if (map[row][col] == 0) { tile[row][col] = new Tile(WALL, false, true, false);  }`? Just making sure I understand correctly.

Comment: exception stacktrace contains the answer. atleast narrow it down to the line the exception is thrown

Comment: @Ata - I already did, I've pointed out what line is causing trouble.

Comment: @dudeprgm - yes, that code line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a NPE in :

```
if (map[row][col] == 0) { tile[row][col] = new Tile(WALL, false, true, false);
```

then there is only 4 solutions:

- map is null
- or map[row] is null
- or tile is null
- or tile[row] is null

Answer (score 1):

After executing this:

```
for (row = 0; row < mapheight; row++){
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(delimiters);
        for (col = 0; col < mapwidth ; col++){
            map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);

        }
    }
```

both `row` and `col` will go out of bound, because of the final row++ and col++. That's why you are getting the out of bound error when trying to access `if (map[row][col] == 0)`

**`NullPointerException`** in an array means you are somehow referencing an index less than 0 or greater than **length()-1**.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, not a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It should cause both, actually. @dudeprgm